# How do I seed default data to Mongo db (or any database) in a microservice architecture?

Tags: mongodb, go, microservices

I have a use case where there are multiple microservices and one of them deals with roles and resources(let's call this microservice as **A**). Resources are just endpoints.

**A** maintains a collection(let's call this **X**) to store all the resources from different microservices. For each microservice other than **A**, I would like to store all of its resources(endpoints) into **X** the first time this microservice boots up.

I am thinking of having a json file with all the resources in each microservice and calling **A**'s endpoint to add resources whenever a microservice boots up.

Is there any idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Idiomatic way to do which part? This is a pretty complex suite of functionality you're describing. There is no one "idiomatic way" to do dynamic data caching at boot plus dynamic runtime reconfiguration.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for pointing out. Specifically, I want to populate default resources for each microservice whenever it boots up for the first time and sync the updates made to the resources.

Comment: You've just restated your question, it's still too broad to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of [Viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) so you can set default data from multiple different sources like yaml, json, remote config like etcd, live watch of files among others. You can algo configure the call to and endpoint with it's [remote configuration](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/master/flags.go) feature.